# Производное и производящие основы

Tags: словообразование

Какие из них производные, а какие производящие?
Бегать – бег
Верить – верный
Верно – верный
Вздох – вздыхать
Двигать – движение

Comment: Это домашнее задание?

Answer (score 0):

Бегать – бег: традиционная русистика скажет вам, что это усечение основы *бегать* и нулевая суффиксация, то есть бег — производная, бегать — производящая.

Хотя разумней, на мой взгляд, считать, что в словаре языка есть элемент бег-, от которого образуется и существительное, и глагол.

Верить – верный: *верный* произведено от *вера*, поэтому в этой паре нельзя установить непосредственные отношения.

Верно – верный: верный — производящая, верно — производная. Считается, что наречия на -о производны от прилагательных.

Вздох – вздыхать: тут опять нельзя установить отношения, так как *вздох* – производное от *вздохнуть*, см. на гласный в корне. От *вздыхать* производно, например, *вздыхание*.

Двигать – движение: двигать — производящая, движение — производная.

Answer (score 0):

Первоначально в языке создаются имена существительные, потом их действия, а потом описания и прочие причастия и деепричастия. И у всех современных слов с окончанием "ние" - суть в том, что это не физический предмет. Вроде и имя существительное, но "на полку его положить нельзя" - по сути это описание или классификация по определенным свойствам. СуждеНИЕ